# Cyclic repeating decimals

Tags: decimal-expansion

I was thinking today that if some fraction $1/n$ where $n$ is an integer has a digital period of $n-1$ then it must be a cyclic number. But Wikipedia says that this does hold but only states it true for when $n$ is prime. Why question is, why does $n$ need to be prime?

Comment: The length of the period of $1/n$ is a divisor of $\phi(n)$. If the length is $n-1$, then $\phi(n)=n-1$ and so $n$ is prime.

Comment: But say we did not know this, can it be said that if the period is $n-1$ then it is a cyclic repeating decimal? And what you have added just further shows that this means that it can only happen when $n$ is in fact prime.

Comment: "But say we did not know this" ... Since "this" is a mathematical theorem, if we don't know it already then it is still possible to prove it. Other than the fact that the answer-in-a-comment could have been written in the answer box (@lhf), I don't see what part of the question is unanswered.

Comment: I mean that I didn’t know that the length of the period of $1/n$ was a divisor of $\phi (n) $ but yet it still seemed like what I said should be true, without knowing that $n$ is prime or not.

Comment: Since you think a number "should" be cyclic if you find that the period is $n-1,$ an obvious question to ask would be, how can you **prove** it? I'm surprised you didn't ask that, but perhaps you got distracted by the idea that there ought to be composite values of $n$ that satisfy the statement. But you know now that there are none. Now what? Do you want a proof that the number is cyclic? (I don't have a proof, but someone else might.)

Comment: Yeah I did manage to prove it.